# rtmfp - NetConnection.Connect.Failed - can't get what's wrong (kaspersky settings)

Tags: actionscript, rtmfp, netconnection

i'm developing an actionscript p2p application. everything worked fine until today.

this is my code:

```
            private function initConnection():void{
                nc = new NetConnection();
                nc.maxPeerConnections = maxPC;
                ExternalInterface.call("alert",maxPC);
                nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncStatus, false, 0, true);
                nc.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS);
            }

            public function ncStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
                if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") initSendStream();
                else if (event.info.code == "NetStream.Connect.Closed") {
                    if (event.info.stream.farID) onPeerDisconnect(event.info.stream.farID);
                }
                else if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Failed") ExternalInterface.call("p2pError", "conFailed")
                else ExternalInterface.call("p2pError", "conFailedUnknown");
            }
```

and i always got it worked. the key and rtmfp-server addres are right.

i can't understand why i allways has "NetConnection.Connect.Failed".

i search on the internet about this question. the possible sollution is to turn off firewall. but it allways turn off at my pc.

so i don't know what to do...

any suggestions?

any help appriciated!

Edit: well guys, i've just solved this problem. i got kaspersky with expired licence. so i turned it off but didn't delete. just turned off. few minutes ago i've deleted it and everything started working fine. but i'm still curious about what settings kaspersky could change. so question still open.

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems coinsedence took place this time. kaspersky had nothing to deal with that. adobe cirrus server was down for few days.